# is it possible for multiple projects to export targets under the same package name?

Tags: cmake

Is it possible for two or more, completely separate, projects to export targets under the same package name in cmake?

so for example, after installing multiple libraries, independently, you would be able to link with them in your own project like so:

```
find_package(SharedPackageName REQUIRED COMPONENTS Lib1 Lib2)

add_executable(MyProgram "main.cpp")
target_link_libraries(MyProgram SharedPackageName::Lib1 SharedPackageName::Lib2)
```

The idea here is to have all my libraries be their own independent projects with their own git repositories, that are installable separately, but at the same time make them appear to be part of a larger "organization" library (by installing each libraries include directory under a shared organization parent directory, and exposing cmake targets under a shared organization package name). Similar to the [c++ boost libraries](https://github.com/boostorg).

I've tried to work out a solution myself however the problem im facing is that whenever i install one of the libraries it overwrites the previous ones cmake config file because they use the same name:

```
project("SharedPackageName")
set(LIB_NAME "Lib1")

add_library("${LIB_NAME}" "src/libsrc.cpp")

target_include_directories("${LIB_NAME}" PUBLIC "include")

install(DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/${PROJECT_NAME}/${LIB_NAME}"
        DESTINATION "include/${PROJECT_NAME}")

install(TARGETS "${LIB_NAME}" 
        EXPORT "${PROJECT_NAME}Config" 
        DESTINATION "lib")

install(EXPORT "${PROJECT_NAME}Config" 
        NAMESPACE "${PROJECT_NAME}::"
        DESTINATION "lib/cmake/${PROJECT_NAME}")
```

Is it perhaps possible to make cmake "append" targets to an existing config file rather than overwriting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just don't set up the targets export  file to use the same name for each subproject. Instead, give them all unique names with a common prefix, like `targets-<subproj>.cmake`. Then create a `<Project>Config.cmake` that globs for `targets-*.cmake` and iterates over the resulting list, `include()`-ing each one. It's OK if every subproject installs the same `<Project>Config.cmake`file, since it should always have the same content.